# Hue won't build due to missing Thrift classes.

Tags: maven, hadoop, thrift, hue

I'm trying to build Hue and it appears to require a Thrift binary that I am missing.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile 

(default-compile) on project hue-plugins: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/kramachandran/Sandbox/hue/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/java/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/thriftfs/DatanodePlugin.java:[32,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class BlockReader
[ERROR] location: package org.apache.hadoop.hdfs
[ERROR] /Users/kramachandran/Sandbox/hue/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/java/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/thriftfs/DatanodePlugin.java:[33,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class RemoteBlockReader
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient
[ERROR] /Users/kramachandran/Sandbox/hue/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/java/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/thriftfs/DatanodePlugin.java:[91,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class BlockReader
[ERROR] BlockReader reader = null;
[ERROR] /Users/kramachandran/Sandbox/hue/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/java/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/thriftfs/DatanodePlugin.java:[95,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: variable RemoteBlockReader
[ERROR] reader = RemoteBlockReader.newBlockReader(getSocket(), block.path, block.blockId,
```

However there is no documentation on how hue and thrift interact.   Specifically, which versions of the thrift binaries are requrired and where they should be placed.

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies are in the [hue pom.xml](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/maven/pom.xml) file

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0-cdh</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libfb303</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0-cdh</version>
      </dependency>
```